# How many positive integer solution pairs $(x, y)$ are there for the equation $y^2 = \frac{(x^5 - 1)}{(x-1)} $, $x\neq 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> How many positive integer solution pairs $(x, y)$ are there for the
>   equation $$y^2 = \frac{(x^5 - 1)}{(x-1)},\;\; x\neq 1\;?$$

Source : [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2016 Junior Catagory](https://matholympiad.org.bd/)

I am unable to find if there are any solutions or not.

Comment: The one you found isn't even correct - the question demands positive integers

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that 0 is not a positive integer. I have edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried to find the first few values of $(x^5-1)/(x-1)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ yet? In particular, have you looked at their prime factors yet?

Comment: @SmileyCraft I understood it now. Thanks for simple explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $y^2=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ for positive integers $x,y$ (and $x\ne 1$).

**Case 1:**  $x$ is even. Then
$$\left(x^2+\frac x2\right)^2=x^4+x^3+\frac14x^2<y^2$$
and
$$\left(x^2+\frac x2+1\right)^2=x^4+x^3+\frac94 x^2+x+1>y^2,$$ 
contradiction as $y^2$ cannot be strictly between two consecutive squares..

**Case 2:** $x$ is odd.  Then 
$$\begin{align}\left(x^2+\frac {x-1}2\right)^2&=x^4+x^3-\frac34x^2-\frac12x+\frac14\\&=y^2-\frac14(7x^2+5x+3)<y^2\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\left(x^2+\frac {x+1}2\right)^2&=x^4+x^3+\frac54x^2+\frac12x+\frac14\\
&=y^2+\frac14(x^2-2x-3)\\&=y^2+\frac14(x+1)(x-3)\\&\ge y^2\end{align}$$
with equality iff $x=3$. In other words, we arrive at a contradiction for odd $x>3$ and at the same time see that $x=3$ leads to a solution.